# I have a random Number Generator that uses a XOR shift algorithm, using a global variable. Is there another method to accomplish this?

Tags: c++, c, random, global-variables

I built this "Random" number Generator, and it works exactly like its supposed to. But I feel like the use of a Global variable in this way is cursed, and there must be a better way of accomplishing the same thing.

```
unsigned int State = 1804289383;
unsigned int get_random_U32_number() {
    unsigned int Number = State;
    Number ^= Number << 13;
    Number ^= Number >> 17;
    Number ^= Number << 5;
    State = Number;
    return Number;
}
```

Not sure what else to try, I can't use any built like function like `rand()` for this project.

Comment: The answer will likely be very different in C and C++. Please choose one of them.

Comment: *But I feel like the use of a Global variable in this way is cursed, and there must be a better way of accomplishing the same thing.* Not really.  See https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.2.2p5  But `static unsigned int State = 1804289383;` would certainly be an improvement.

Comment: But it is not random, you will get the same numbers every time. You need to find some source of entropy. What is your operating system?

Comment: @0___________ The point is to get the same Numbers every time.

Comment: @user17732522 An answer in any language is fine. This code also works in both C and C++

Comment: @cw123 You are asking a question that is about design choices which are completely different in idiomatic C and C++. If I answer that you should use a class with member functions to represent the random number generator, then that will be irrelevant to a C programmer reading this and if I answer that you can represent the random number generator as a structure that can be passed to your function as a pointer, then it would be bad advice for C++ programmers to use this approach.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thank You, the link you posted is very helpful.

Comment: In C++ you would write it as an object, and encapsulate `State` as an instance variable set by the constructor. That way you could have multiple PRNG objects with distinct states, and you would have reproducibility without lock-in to a single stream of values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach, slightly different from @dbush's answer:

```
unsigned int get_random_U32_number( void ) {
    static unsigned int State = 1804289383;

    unsigned int Number = State;
    Number ^= Number << 13;
    Number ^= Number >> 17;
    Number ^= Number << 5;
    State = Number;
    return Number;
}
```

The change to `get_random_U32_number( void )` makes it explicit that the function takes no arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your function to take the address of the current state variable as a parameter.

```
unsigned int get_random_U32_number(unsigned int *State) {
    unsigned int Number = *State;
    Number ^= Number << 13;
    Number ^= Number >> 17;
    Number ^= Number << 5;
    *State = Number;
    return Number;
}
```

This allows the function to be reentrant.

Comment: `unsigned int Number = State;` should be `unsigned int Number = *State;`

Answer (score 0):

Make it `static` to reduce its scope to the local file.

```
// unsigned int State = 1804289383;
static unsigned int State = 1804289383;
```